# nextProps is not shown in my componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning the life cycle method of reactjs. To get into deeper understanding, I am trying to learn by creating self example. What i did is, i made an object called colors, i passed them down to the ColorButtons component. The colors object is fetched to show the buttons based on the colors that are in the props. I could show the button, but when i click on, let's say #fd5c63 color button, some event should occur. If i click on the same button again and again, the page should not be re-rendered. If i am right, I have to use componentWillRecieveProps and shouldComponentUpdate. That is why i am wanting to understand them deeply. If my understanding is right regarding the re-render part, why my componentWillRecieveProps is not showing anything in the console? Can anyone please help me to understand the scenario i am talking about?

Here is my code

```
const colors = [
  {id:1, color: '#00a98f'},
  {id:2, color: '#fd5c63'},
  {id:3, color: '#49176d'}
];

render(<ColorButtons colors = {colors} />, document.querySelector('#app'))

class ColorButtons extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(`nextProps ${nextProps}`);
  }

 render() {
     const colorBtn = () => this.props.colors.map((color, i) => 
                                  <ColorButton 
                                    color={color.color} 
                                    key={color.id} 
                                    onClick={()=>console.log(color.color)}
                                  />
         );
    return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Title>Hello World, this is my first styled component!</Title>
      {colorBtn()}
    </Wrapper>
    ) 
  }                                 
}

export default ColorButtons;
```

This is the working example

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kif7NlLz5BCDXQ18fyg

Comment: What's the problem? The code works exactly as told, and remember that `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called on initial mounting. It is only called when a mounted component gets new props, not when state changes and the component rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple - you're not changing the props.

Here's a small test that will trigger your console.log line on clicking:

```
class ButtonSwitcher extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      colors: [
        {id:1, color: '#00a98f'},
        {id:2, color: '#fd5c63'},
        {id:3, color: '#49176d'}
      ]
    } 
  }

  render() {
    const colors = this.state.colors
    const onClick = ()=> {
      const [a, b, c] = this.state.colors
      this.setState({colors: [b, c, a]})
    }

    return (
      <div onClick={onClick}>
        <ColorButtons colors = {colors} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<ButtonSwitcher/>, document.querySelector('#app'))
```